# Splitting a column into two?

Tags: sql-server

I'm using this,

```
ALTER Table Analytics.dbo.[Parent Table]
ADD [Cost Center] AS Left([Cost Center1], Charindex(':', [Cost Center1])-1)

ALTER Table Analytics.dbo.[Parent Table]
ADD [Project] as Substring([Cost Center1], Charindex(':', [Cost Center1])+1,
              len([Cost Center1])-Len(Charindex(':', [Cost Center1])))
```

This works well. But the problem now is that the column, CostCenter1, has many entries which have '-' instead of ':'. How to split the complete column now?

Comment: So `[Cost Center1]` can have both `:` and `-` . Show sample data and expected result with data covering your current problem

Comment: Just replace "-" with ":" before you charindex with ":".

Comment: So, I have a few entries like 5000:gsasd, 4534:fbgajf, 35253-adsg, 324-adsg in Cost Center1

I have to split the data such that the part before ':' and '-' goes to Cost Center and data after both of them goes to Project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update all data with code which is given below

```
UPDATE MyTable

SET columnName = REPLACE (columnName, '-', ':');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [REPLACE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms186862(v=sql.120).aspx) function against `Cost Center1` :

```
ALTER Table Analytics.dbo.[Parent Table]
ADD [Cost Center] AS Left([Cost Center1], Charindex(':', REPLACE([Cost Center1],'-',':'))-1)

ALTER Table Analytics.dbo.[Parent Table]
ADD [Project] as Substring([Cost Center1], Charindex(':', REPLACE([Cost Center1],'-',':'))+1,
              len([Cost Center1])-Len(Charindex(':', REPLACE([Cost Center1],'-',':'))))
```